# An abelian group is finite $\iff$ the kernel of a surjective homomorphism has rank $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups

I'm doing a course on lineare algebra and I have to show the following:

> let $H$ be a finitely generated abelian group and $g: \mathbb{Z}^n \to H$ a surjective homomorphism.
>   I want to show that $H$ is finite $\iff$ the $kernel$ of g has $rank=n$.

since g is a surjective homomorphism follows that

• $g( 1_{\mathbb{Z}} )=1_{H}$

• $g(a^{-1}) = g(a)^{-1}$

• $\forall a \in H \space \exists a' \in \mathbb{Z}^n : g(a')=a$

but how shall I use those properties? I sincerely don't have any Idea since I did not already follow the algebra course and this seems to me more an "algebra problem" than a "lineare algebra problem". Could you maybe help me? Some hints would be really appreciated :-)

Comment: By a subspace of rank $n$ doesn't it mean subspace is whole space... :O I am not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be useful to see $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z^n$ as a part of the vector space $\def\Q{\Bbb Q}\Q^n$ at some places (though I am not sure this approach is intended).

The main non obvious thing here is that every subgroup $K$ of $\Z^n$ has a rank, namely that it is generated by a set of linearly independent elements (over$~\Z$, which implies independence over$~\Q$), and that the number of generators (which gives the rank) depends only on$~K$ (you can get the latter but not the former from linear algebra over$~\Q$). But apparently this is supposed to be known.

Now first suppose the rank $r$ of $K=\ker(g)$, which clearly cannot exceed$~n$, is actually less than $n$. Then there exist some element $v\in\Z^n$ linearly independent of the generators of$~K$, so that $mv\in K$ with $m\in\Z$ is only satisfied for $m=0$; this means $g(v)$ has infinite order in $H$, and $H$ must be infinite.

Conversely assume $r=n$. Then viewed as elements of$~\Q^n$ the generators of$~K$ span the whole space. The standard basis elements can be expressed as rational linear combinations of the generators of$~K$. Then for each of then some integer multiple lies in $K$ (all its coefficients when expressed on the basis of$~K$ become integer). This means the image of each standard basis element under $g$ has finite order in$~H$. But an Abelian group generated by finitely many elements of finite order is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $|H|=k$, then try to show $(k,k,\dots,k)\in \ker g$. Conversely, assume $(k,k,\dots,k)\in\ker g$, show that $H$ is finite (it is here that you need $g$ surjective).

Comment: oups typo, I correct the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$N\le\Bbb Z^n\;\;\text{has finite index}\;\;\iff \text{rank}\,(N)=n\iff N\cong\Bbb Z^n$$

If yu have the above you have the answer of your question.

Hint for the hint's proof:

If $\;[\Bbb Z^n:N]=\infty\implies \exists\,a\in\Bbb Z^n\;\;s.t.\;\;\left|\langle a+N\rangle\right|=\infty\iff \exists\,\overline K\le\Bbb Z^n/N\;\;with\;\;\overline K\cong\Bbb Z$

Comment: I was thinking of same thing (see my comment above)... by kernel being  a subspace of rank $n$ it means $g$ is trivial map right? :O Am i missing something... :O

Comment: What vector spaces are you thinking of, @PraphullaKoushik ? These are free abelian groups...

Comment: I mean subgroup of rank $n$ ... I am not able to express my idea as i am not very familiar with finitely generated groups

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I see. The problem is *almost* trivial if one has the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups which, apparenty, the OP hasn't yet covered. And no: if $\;\text{rank}\ker g=n\;$ it doesn't mean the map is the trivial one.

Comment: Ok.. I would just see what would you discuss with OP as i do not know what to ask and not sure what to say :)

Comment: Don Antonio, thank you very much for your effort. Unfortunately I did not understand what you have written because I've never seen it in my life. Tomorrow I'll speak with my assistant to get some hint from him and maybe what you have written will be clearer.Have a nice evening, I'll try again tomorrow.